# How to save plots in grayscale

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, color

As sophomoric as this question seems, how should I save plots in grayscale in Mathematica?

I generally like eps images for their scalability and I use ghostscript or other third party perl scripts to convert my images to grayscale.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way would be to use `ColorConvert` to convert the `RGB` or `Hue` values to gray scale. Here's an example:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Exp[-x^2], Sinc[π x]}, {x, 0, π}] /. 
  x : _RGBColor | _Hue | _CMYKColor :> ColorConvert[x, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]
[image]

For 2D plots that accept a `ColorFunction`, you can simply use `GrayLevel` to get the plot in grayscale as:

```
DensityPlot[
  Sin[x ^2 + y^2], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image]
[image]

---

Typically, these grayscale plots are useful when submitting to journals that charge exorbitant prices just to print in colour. However, just a note of caution that discerning different shades of gray is not easy. For the most effect, it is recommended (at least in the journals I publish in), that you also change the line type for your different curves (and not more than 4 curves/plot). You should also choose the colours (or colourscale, for 2D surface plots) wisely so that they convert well to grayscale. For example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ahh, I was trying to figure out how to use ColorConvert without changing the entire plot to an Image, which then loses it's vector goodness.

Comment: I got this somewhere (may be on Mathematica.SE?) `toGrayScale[y_] := y /. x__?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor}, Head[#]] &) :> ColorConvert[x, "Grayscale"]` so that it can be done as an afterthought. e.g. `ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 15, 2}]] // toGrayScale`; it works also on `ContourPlot` etc... (not very different from the solution above though !)

Comment: @chris You probably got that from this answer :) See the edit history... Mr.Wizard simply rephrased that more concisely

Comment: Apart from `GrayLevel[]`, there's also `ColorData["GrayTones"]`.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to roll your own color functions. For continuous use:

```
grayScale = Blend[{Black, White}, #1] &

ContourPlot[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> grayScale]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For discrete plots:

```
grayColorList = (Blend[{Black, White}, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1])

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> grayColorList[[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In what way does your `grayScale` function differ from the built-in `GrayLevel`?

Comment: It doesn't, I just didn't remember about GrayLevel :)