# Plot curves different way so that one can see them when printing black and white

Tags: plotting, color

I am going to plot for instance:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
   PDF[ExponentialDistribution[#]][x] & /@ {1/2, 1/5, 1/25, 
      1/1000}], {x, 0, 50}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Now, when someone prints this black and white, I would want him to be able to distinguish between the curves (a line, then a dotted line and so on). How would you suggest me to change the code, to achieve this goal?

Comment: Also see the last part of [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3245/5) to plotting in grayscale

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to `Dashing`, there are also `DotDashed` and `Dotted` line styles. So you could define a set of plot styles as follows, varying first the dashing and second the gray shade:

```
styles = Flatten@
  Table[{Directive[color], Directive[Dashed, color], 
    Directive[DotDashed, color], 
    Directive[Dotted, color]}, {color, {Black, Gray}}]
```

Then the plot that is supposed to be printed in black and white would be created by this:

```
p = Plot[Evaluate[
   PDF[ExponentialDistribution[#]][x] & /@ {1/2, 1/5, 1/25, 
     1/1000}], {x, 0, 50}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```

[image: Line styles]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Here's one quick way:

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate[
    PDF[ExponentialDistribution[#]][x] & /@ {1/2, 1/5, 1/25, 
      1/1000}], {x, 0, 50}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True];
cols = Cases[plot, _Hue, Infinity];
plot /. Thread[cols -> Map[Dashing, {{}, Tiny, Small, Medium}]]
```

[image: dashed plots]

In general, you can replace the `Map[Dashing, {{}, Tiny, Small, Medium}]` in the last line with a list of plotting styles whose length is the same as the number of function you originally plotted. If you want to use a compound style (e.g. you want the curve to be slightly thicker as well as dashed), you will want to use `Directive[]` in conjunction with `Thickness[]`/`AbsoluteThickness[]` and `Dashing[]`/`AbsoluteDashing[]`.

Comment: Note: this is for the case where you've already generated a color version, and you want a monochrome one. If you are generating a monochrome one from the outset, use the `PlotStyle` option of `Plot[]`.

Answer (score 7):

You could also generate your plot, and then click multiple times to select the various curves, and set the dashing pattern via the **Graphics > Drawing Tools** palette.  Under the section for **Stroke**, you have some additional patterns.

For example: `Dashing[{0, Small, 0, Small, Medium, Small}]` which is a `-..-..-..-` pattern.

Answer (score 7):

The `Monochrome` plot theme was made for this. It uses black curves with different types of dashing to distinguish the functions:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
     PDF[ExponentialDistribution[#]][x] & /@ {1/2, 1/5, 1/25, 1/1000}], 
     {x, 0, 50}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]