# Running out of PlotStyles for multiple curves within one graph in black and white

Tags: plotting

This is related to the following thread
["Plot curves different way so that one can see them when printing black and white"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/plot-curves-different-way-so-that-one-can-see-them-when-printing-black-and-white)

But because my curves are close to each other in some regions, so just manipulating the "dotted" and "dashed" cannot clearly distinguish those curves in those regions. Changing thickness works better, but is not aesthetically pleasing.

I've seen the following cross-dotted style, can Mathematica replicate it? Or something similar such as strings of tiny squares or circles etc?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this is by using `ListPlot` witch has an option `PlotMarkers`. It can be anything:

```
 ListPlot[
    Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi, 0.1}],
    PlotMarkers -> "x"
 ]
```

will yield this
[image]
or even this:

```
ListPlot[
   Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi, 0.1}],
   PlotMarkers -> (\!\(\*
      GraphicsBox[
      TagBox[PolygonBox[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}],
      "Triangle"],
      ImageSize->{13.999999999999815`, Automatic}]\))
]
```

with the following result

[image]

Have a look at the reference page [PlotMarkers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html)

**EDIT**

Saw the comment right before posting, but still here's how I would have done it:

```
SetAttributes[StepData, HoldAll];
StepData[fun_, xMin_, xMax_, dStep_] := Module[
   {xCur},
   xCur = xMin;
   res = Reap[
      While[xCur <= xMax,
       Sow[{xCur, fun[xCur]}];
       xCur += dx /. FindRoot[
          EuclideanDistance[{xCur, fun[xCur]}, {xCur + dx, fun[xCur + dx]}] == dStep,
          {dx, 0, 0, dStep}
          ];
       ]
      ][[2, 1]];
   Return[res];
   ];

func[x_] := Sin[x];
ListPlot[
 StepData[func, 0, Pi, 0.5],
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[
    {Black, Thin, Line[{{-0.1, -0.1}, {+0.1, +0.1}}], 
     Line[{{-0.1, +0.1}, {+0.1, -0.1}}]}
    ], 0.05}
 ]
```

With the following result
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt help! But is it possible to allocate the tiny marks evenly?

Comment: @Wendy that can be done, but it is non-trivial unless your curves are really straight lines or simple functions whose inverse is known. See the answers to this question for the general case: [Generating evenly-spaced points on a curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve).

Comment: Updated my answer.