# Export grayscale png

Tags: export, image

The help for the `Export` function is absolutely unclear. How can I specify options for my output format?

According to the documentation, [PNG](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PNG.html) supports grayscale output. But this doesn't work, I still get an RGB image.

```
Export["somefile.png", something, "ColorSpace" -> "Grayscale"]
```

Comment: I think `ColorSpace` works only with `Import`, not with `Export`. Perhaps, you can `ColorConvert[something,"Grayscale"]` and then export as a workaround?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8818/121

Answer (score 7):

The following solution works as a formatting step prior to performing the export of your output

(Please note that *this is not my solution!* it was posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/how-to-save-plots-in-grayscale) by [@rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rfwas) 
- i'm reposting it because it got a little lost in the comments/editing of the other question and it seems to be a very effective post-processing method).

Where other approaches do not work, this one seems to get over the line.

```
toGrayScale[y_] := y /. x__?
(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor}, Head[#]] &) :> ColorConvert[x, "Grayscale"]

greyscalemyPlot = myPlot // toGrayScale

Export["greyscale-myplot.eps", greyscalemyPlot]
```

I found this particularly useful when I have an array of plots like a `GraphicsGrid` of `ListPlots` or where I have used `Show` to overlay two plots. in both cases it is a pain to go back in and modify the options using `GreyLevel` etc.

Comment: @rm -rf, yes, that is what I meant, thanks. Happy to remove this answer if you want to post similar or simply redirect back to the original answer. As I said I have found it to be a very handy post-processing approach. Cheers.

Comment: Alternatively: `toGrayScale[y_] := y /. x : (_RGBColor | _Hue | _CMYKColor) :> ColorConvert[x, GrayLevel]`

Comment: @Grrwebb No worries, you don't have to delete this at all; I'm glad that you found it useful :)

Answer (score 5):

The documentation can be a bit confusing sometimes, but in this case it is clearly stated in the *elements* section of the [png help-page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PNG.html)

[image]

The option "ColorSpace" is only for `Import`.

Anyway, what happens when you `Export` a png-file is, that (when it is a `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`) *Mathematica* calls `Rasterize` which accepts the `ColorSpace` option. Therefore one solution to your problem is to use

```
Export["tmp/gray.png", Rasterize[p, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"]]
```

A quick test shows, that it creates identical images which only differ in `ColorSpace`

```
p = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}];
Export["tmp/color.png", p]
Export["tmp/gray.png", Rasterize[p, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"]]

Function[{img}, 
   Import[img, #] & /@ {"BitDepth", "ColorSpace", "DataType", 
     "ImageSize"}] /@ {col, gray} // Column
(*
 {8,RGBColor,Integer,{360,281}}
 {8,GrayLevel,Integer,{360,281}}
*)
```

and they fit exactly onto another

```
ImageMultiply @@ (Import /@ {col, gray})
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]