# MatrixPlot for DFT in black and white with ContourLabel

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-8

I have several data files such as this:

```
{{0, 2.86088, 4.44366, 50.9516, 3.26578, 3.76921, 10.2211}, {0.382102,
   0.399499, 0.633217, 0.458334, 0.772598, 1.04943, 
  0.245786}, {2.17053, 0.753159, 1.57424, 0.378372, 0.82554, 0.651859,
   0.571577}, {50.5039, 3.35749, 1.70239, 0.205699, 2.27276, 1.42459, 
  7.90045}, {1.47175, 0.712629, 0.842982, 0.220806, 0.294048, 0.21267,
   0.166509}, {0.814432, 1.12644, 0.729741, 0.788745, 0.183342, 
  0.248011, 0.180827}, {10.4399, 1.53087, 1.52872, 8.1604, 0.480033, 
  0.538012, 1.29091}}
```

These are discrete fourier transform frequency values. When I plot them with `MatrixPlot` on **mathematica 8.0**, I get this:

[image]

Now this is what I would like to do and I got the idea from reading about [plotting with tooltips](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2512/204) and the [ContourLabel option in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourLabels.html):

1. I would like my `MatrixPlot` to be in black and white/monochrome. This is because I would like to include these plots in journal publications and save money over having color images (It's **$325 per color image** on [*Physics of fluids*](http://pof.aip.org/authors/publication_charges) for instance). 
   I have tired the `ColorFunction->"Monochrome"` option with `MatrixPlot` and have also tried `ArrayPlot` to get black and white spots instead of the orange and yellow spots that I have.
2. Can I have an option like `ContourLabel` for `MatrixPlot` so that I can entirely circumvent having a color bar?
3. To those of you who have published with plots from Mathematica 8.0, what would you do?
4. I have access to Mathematica 8.0 right now and for convenience I would like to stick to that.

I have tried to search around here but didn't find an answer that would suit my needs. Having said that, please feel free to yell at me if I didn't search hard enough!

Comment: Use `ArrayPlot`. Also this: [How to save plots in grayscale](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3245/5)

Comment: @rm-rf I used `ArrayPlot`. All I get now is dark blobs. I am fine with that as it suits my needs. However, how do I **mark** individual points on this plot now?

Comment: `ArrayPlot@mat` should give you mostly white blobs. Using it with `ColorFunction -> GrayLevel` will give you black blobs. Also, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10521/5) (and the one under it) for marking individual points on the squares.

Comment: @rm-rf Wow this seems ridiculously complicated enough to be a mini project!

Comment: Actually, it's not... it should be pretty simple. You have all the ingredients in the two answers above, and they should all work with mma 8 and older. In any case, if you're trying to make publication quality graphics, better to spend some time getting it right than do a rush job :). BTW, a lot of my journals do not require me to send in a grayscale graphics. They use color for the online version and they do the conversion to B&W for print. You might want to check with yours if they do that.

Comment: @rm-rf Thank you for the encouragement and also the vital information that some journals perhaps would do their own color-B&W thingy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {5, 10}]

max = Max[mat]

ArrayPlot[Reverse@mat, 
 Epilog -> {MapIndexed[{If[#1 < .5 max, Black, White], 
      Text[#1, Reverse[#2], {1.2, 1.2}]} &, mat, {2}]}, 
 FrameTicks -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this what you mean by wanting to add ContourLabels?

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant.

Comment: So this displays numbers for all those values that are less than 0.5 the Maximum of `mat`? How can I change the number of decimal points?

Comment: @drN This displays numbers for all elements ... just look at the figure, don't all of them have numbers?  Regarding your other question, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8923/formatting-a-number-with-fixed-number-of-significant-digits

Comment: clearly, I was not thinking!